# Need to convert an output of a command to a comma separated values in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a code that produces the output in the following way in shell script. I need this output in a comma separated format. This is a sample output, actual number of values etc may vary as per the given inputs but the overall format of output will remain same.

```
------------------------
| column_name          |
------------------------
| TB_CODIGO            |
| TB_ELEMENT           |
| TB_INGLES            |
| TB_IMSS              |
| TB_NUMERO            |
| TB_TEXTO             |
| LLAVE                |
------------------------
```

I want the output in below format:

```
TB_CODIGO,TB_ELEMENT,TB_INGLES,TB_IMSS,TB_NUMERO,TB_TEXTO,LLAVE
```

Comment: Are you getting this output from an sql client? If so, I'm pretty sure it has a `--raw` flag or similar which would get you the result in a format more adapted to parsing

Comment: I am doing like this but not getting accurate result. my_command | tr -d '|' | tr -d '-'   | tr '\n' ',' | tr -d ' '

Answer (score 0):

One more way through example:

```
echo "
------------------------
| column_name          |
------------------------
| TB_CODIGO            |
| TB_ELEMENT           |
| TB_INGLES            |
| TB_IMSS              |
| TB_NUMERO            |
| TB_TEXTO             |
| LLAVE                |
------------------------
" | sed 's/[|,-]//g' | paste -d, -s | tr -d '[[:space:]]' | sed -e 's/,,//g' -e 's/column_name//g'

TB_CODIGO,TB_ELEMENT,TB_INGLES,TB_IMSS,TB_NUMERO,TB_TEXTO,LLAVE
```

So, generic way is as follows:

```
<your_mysql_output> | sed 's/[|,-]//g' | paste -d, -s | tr -d '[[:space:]]' | sed -e 's/,,//g' -e 's/column_name//g'
```

If you suppress column headers and borders in the MySQL query itself, you can minimize the parsing of the column names and border characters. 
For instance,

```
mysql -u root -p -s -r -e "show databases;"
Enter password: 
Database
information_schema
mysql
test
```